# How to display images larger than 33k in a Image control?

Tags: wpf

I try to display really huge(4k * 120k or larger like 4k * 300k) images in an Image control in WPF.
Although it's only displaying the first part of the image correctly, around 33k row, the display becomes garbage(black in this case, but it's dependent on the image).
[image: Before 33k row]

[image: After]

The XAML code for the image control.
View is a BitmapImage and setting the DecodePixelHeight won't help either.

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
            <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="viewImage" 
                   Source="{Binding View}" />
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Am i doing something wrong, or there is a limitation in the size of the Image control?

Comment: See the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks) on BitmapSource: *The maximum height and width of an image is 2^16 pixels ...*

Comment: Thanks, that's explains a lot.

Answer (score -1):

As Clemens mentioned, BitmapSource has a 2^16 limit in dimensions.
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks)